# Price filter is not working without submit button using jquery and PHP

Tags: php

I have tried various solutions but all are working if i used with submit button. But I need a solution- passing value to php POST/GET(method) with jquery submit only. 
Thanks in advance.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount']);
    $values = str_replace(' ','',$_POST['amount']);
    $values = str_replace('$','',$values);
    $values = explode('-',$values);
    $min = $values[0];
    $max = $values[1];
    $select_min_value = $_POST['select_min_value'];
    $select_max_value = $_POST['select_max_value'];
    $res = mysql_query('select id,name,image,price,discount from products where price BETWEEN "'.$select_min_value.'" AND "'.$select_max_value.'"');
    $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
    $HTML='';
    if($count > 0)
    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    code;
     }
     }
     else {
     $HTML ='no products';
    }}
    else{
    $min =0;
    $max=35000;
    $HTML='search products';
     }
    echo $HTMl;
```

My javascript code

```
<script>
     $(function () {
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 350000,
            values: [ <?php echo $min; ?>, <?php echo $max; ?> ],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ]);
                var select_min_value = ui.values[ 0 ];
                var select_max_value = ui.values[ 1 ];
                $("#amount_txt").val(select_min_value + '-' + select_max_value);
                $("#filter_min_price").text("$" + select_min_value);
                $("#filter_max_price").text("$" + select_max_value);

            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                var select_min_value = ui.values[ 0 ];
                var select_max_value = ui.values[ 1 ];
                 alert(select_min_value);
                alert(select_max_value);
            $('#filter_product').trigger('submit',['select_min_value','select_max_value']);

             }

        });
        $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
                " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

    });
</script>
```

HTML form

```
 <form action="filter.php" id="filter_product" name="filter_product" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                   <div id="slider-range"></div>
                        <div class="range_cont clearfix">
                            <div  class="pull-left" id="filter_min_price">$<?php echo $min; ?></div>
                            <div  class="pull-right" id="filter_max_price">$<?php echo $max; ?></div>
                        </div>
                   <input type="hidden" name="submit" id="submit" />
                          </form>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please show something...

Comment: Please add more information so we can reproduce the scenario.

Comment: Ys. i edited the code.please check now. Its not working.

Comment: you're checking `$_POST['submit']` but as you say there is no submit button. why not check a value you actually use, like `$_POST['amount']`?

Comment: Hi maxton..I also tried with $_POST['amount'] but it doesn't seems working. I think there is need to pass var select_min_value and var select_max_value to php post function. but i dnt how to pass these values. :(

Comment: Use an input type="hidden" field.

Comment: I think I found his problem, naming an element "submit" will prevent you from accessing the form's "submit" method as the property will instead reference the element rather than the submit method.

Answer (score 0):

If the submit button has a `name="submit"`, when the form is submit with the submit button, this field is also sent with the form. If you'd like to submit the form via JavaScript, then this field will not be sent along with the form. So if you're checking for `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` in PHP, then you'll either need to revise your PHP logic to detect the form being submit via JavaScript in some manner. A few options, depending on your needs, would be to revise your JavaScript to insert a hidden field into the form with the name "submit" or you can revise your PHP to check for the HTTP Request method used to submit the form. Thus you'd adjust your condition to:
`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){`
you can also check for fields you're expecting to be submit with the form, like your code expects `$_POST['amount']` to exist, so you could adjust your if-statement to check that it exists:
`if(isset($_POST['amount'])){`
Which you use is personal preference, I prefer the latter though to make sure all the fields I need are set before I expect them to exist in order to prevent errors if someone forged a request without the required field.

**Edit:**
it sounds like your code never worked in the first place, submit button or not.
You'll need to add all the post data you need to the form. Thus, you'll need to add:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="select_min" name="select_min" value="<?php echo $min; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="select_max" name="select_max" value="<?php echo $min; ?>">
```

Next, you'll need to adjust your JavaScript, so when you change the slider, that you update the hidden fields:

```
    change: function (event, ui) {
        var select_min_value = ui.values[ 0 ];
        var select_max_value = ui.values[ 1 ];
        $('#select_min').val(select_min_value);
        $('#select_max').val(select_max_value);
        $('#filter_product').trigger('submit',['select_min_value','select_max_value']);

     }
```

You'll also need to make a few adjusts after that probably. Try adding: `print_r($_POST);` to the top of your page to make sure the post data is getting sent properly. From there, it should be easy sailing to make final adjustments.

As a final point, the `mysql_*` functions are depreciated. Switch over to mysqli or pdo when writing new code.

**Edit 2:**

The logic `$('#filter_product').trigger('submit',['select_min_value','select_max_value']);` will not submit the form if your form has an element named "submit" in it, since then `myForm.submit()` will error since it's a reference to the form's "submit" element, and thus you cannot submit the form like this. So if you remove such an element from your form, then `myForm.submit` will reference the function rather than the element, and you can submit the form dynamically like this. The same goes for using jQuery's trigger with submit on the form.

Once you remove this element from your form, JavaScript should submit the form successfully, and you'll have to adjust your PHP for the absence of the element.

But if removing the "submit" element is not an option, you can get the submit function in another manner:

```
document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('filter_product'));
```

Comment: Thanks for this clearification. But as u say i also used with hidden filed in form. But still my code does'nt seems working. your concept right it needs proper post method .can u give me any working example.

Comment: Updated, see my edit. Also, I don't see an "amount" field in any of your code though, so not sure what you were trying to do with that when reading `$_POST['amount']`. You'll probably have to adjust the PHP a bit more, but I fixed the JavaScript for you.

Comment: Now values are changing while slider scrolls, but again problem occurs in php code, Js unable to call php post function. I added the hidden field with submit, but still no progress. Is any solution for that?